# Sending Events API (Output Adapter / Consumer resource) from FIWARE CEP: poor documentation

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I'm trying to trigger an event sending to a consumer according to the [DOCS](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification#Sending_Events_API) for FIWARE CEP PROTON. There should be a resource in the API to which one can `POST` and that action should trigger sending output events to consumer.

However, it is not clear if mentioned resource is a literal or variable string. In docs it says: `POST localhost:8080/application-name/consumer`. I have tried using the name of CEP application I made and deployed to engine, name of the consumer used in that app and combinations with literals from the example, but not one of the resources exist.

Anyone ever used this resource from the API? It would be very helpful to debug with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what your question is. Do you want to POST input events to proton? You can do that using:

```
 POST http://{host}:8080/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events
 application/json
```

and your event:

```
{"Name": "event_type_name", "attr1": "value1", "attr2": "value2"}
```

ProtonOnWebServer is the name of my instance.

You can use any application like POSTER for Firefox.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Hi, Naster. Thanks for the response, but it seems I was not clear enough. I have edited my question to explain better. I want to use the API to trigger Output Adapter (push events to Consumer), as is explained in docs (link leads to that chapter of the doc). Have you tried that one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the CEP to send output events through REST, you need to add a consumer of type REST to your CEP application definition. In this REST consumer definition, you need to specify the REST service url.
Please note, that this REST service is not a CEP service. The CEP activates external REST service as a client.
In the CEP [user guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_IBM_Proactive_Technology_Online_User_and_Programmer_Guide), under Consumers -> Rest, you can see more details on the various attributes of this consumer definition.

From that user guide:

**Rest** – this adapter type is a REST client that POSTs events to an external REST
service upon detection of derived events. A Rest type consumer has the following
additional built-in parameters:

- URL – the fully qualified URL of the REST service for event push operation
  using the POST method.
- ContentType – can be "text/plain", "application/xml", or "application/json". This is defined by the REST service.
- AuthToken – an optional parameter, that when set, is added as an X-Auth-Token
  HTTP header of the request.

Comment: Dear @tal-haham, thank you for an answer. I did all of that, and I can also POST to CEP and "provoke" an output event (if condition is satisfied). However in the [DOCS](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification#Sending_Events_API) it is sad that one can "Send a derived event to a consumer" by POSTing to this URL> //localhost:8080/application-name/consumer. Can you please give an example of this action?

Comment: Glad the input side works for you. For sending output events from the CEP using the REST consumer, the application you want the CEP to send output event to needs to have a REST service. This is not a CEP service, but external application service. If the external application has a REST service, the CEP consumer can send this external service a POST command with the event data